# How can i do message packet signing using javascript/node js for MAVLink v2 messages

Tags: ardupilot, mavlink

I am trying to control ardupilot using nodejs. My requirement is to use Javascript solution instead of Python/C.

The [mavlink.io page for supported languages](https://mavlink.io/en/#supported_languages) shows javascript generated library has only support for MAVLink v1, but the graphic in the page shows support for v2. I am confused whether javascript/ node js can handle MAVlink v2 messages. If so, how can message signing be achieved with javascript? I have come across articles detailing the signing process for C/Python but none for javascript. Does this mean javascript support is very limited and may get phased out in the future. I am really confused here, kindly help me out.